# Is it possible to put in-memory file into camel pipeline?

Tags: java, file, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile` in memory and I want to route it into filesystem.

For examplde for sftp I could write something like this:

```
public class DummyRoute extends RouteBuilder {
...
    from("sftp://tester@localhost:22/myFolder?password=password&username=tester&idempotent=true")
        .to("file://ftp_files");
```

Is it possible toi make something like this for usual file in memory?

### P.S.

I understand that I can save file to the first folder and write camel route to watch this directory but it is useless resource wasting

Answer (score 1):

It is working:

```
@Autowired
ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;
....
    producerTemplate.sendBody("seda:rest_upload", multipartFile.getBytes());
```

and on another side:

```
from("seda:rest_upload")
```